# PickerView shows only '?'

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

This is my source code and what I have done is make picker view on storyBoard. Make IBOutlet in this controller by contorl+drag.

It can be compiled however, only '?' appears in the picker view.

Where is the problem?

```
import UIKit

class SelectViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{
    var songNames = ["test1","test2","test3"]

    @IBOutlet weak var songPicker: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){ 
        songPicker.delegate = self
        songPicker.dataSource = self

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return songNames.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int) -> String? {
        return songNames[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is anything showing in the console? Can you show a screenshot of this? Also, what happens if you hard code the string ... `return "Blah"` instead of returning from the array. Also, if `songNames` doesn't change it should be a `let`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed the `forComponent` parameter from the dataSource method. Add it in your `titleForRow` function like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return songNames[row]
}
```

This should fix the problem you are having.

Comment: This is effectively doing nothing.

Comment: His _titleForRow_ delegate method has missing parameter _forComponent_.

Comment: This is why answers that have the text "Could you try this solution" with no other details are a bad idea. (Especially when you change a more obvious bit of code). Comment your code and comment your answers. You now have a down vote for an answer that is technically correct (but still a poor answer).

Comment: Thanks for your warning. I just updated my explanation. I hope it looks better now :)

Comment: Much better now :D

Comment: Thank you again :D

Comment: Thank you very much ! kkakkurt and Fogmeister , your answer is very easy to understand.